# Should I modify the kernel inside docker or in my host to correct "netdata warning"?

Tags: linux, docker, kernel, netdata

I am installing netdata in a docker container and it tells me :

> "Memory de-duplication instructions, You have kernel memory de-duper  available, but it is not currently enabled. To enable it run :"

```
echo 1 >/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run && echo 1000 >/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_millisecs
```

It also say "If you enable it, you will save **40-60%** of netdata memory."

Should I run this command in my host or inside the docker container ?

**Edit**

I am running my docker container using:

```
  net:        host
  privileged: true
  pid:        host
```

Comment: I would say in the docker container due it's the one which is going to run netdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be run inside the container.

The netdata program is running inside the docker container and doesn't have access to the host's filesystem. So running the command on the host will be useless since the changes in the files `/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run` and `/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_millisecs` will not be seen by programs running inside the container.

Comment: I've updated with some of my docker configure -host privliged

Comment: @BigDong the same applies. The commad should be run inside the container

Comment: When you say that running the same command on the host will be useless, do you mean they will not affect the system in any way?

Comment: @BigDong the memory de-duper is usually enabled by default on linux. You can check the files on ur host to be sure.  But even if u enable it on the host netdata will still give u the warning because it can't read the files on the host.